# GitHub SSH was configured and worked AOK for a few days, then crashed and burned. Why? Debug Stack attached

Tags: git, shell, github, ssh, permission-denied

I key-gen'd new ed25519 keys, loaded to GitHub, deleted the retired ssh private keys, restarted the SSH server, re-added the new key, tested it:

ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOTRWZ1iXwJS9jPsv/dcgxCg2rjNnOi+iO59loLav617 email@gmail.com

Everything AOK on my side.

Then, I rebooted my server, re-gen'd new keys and started the entire process over from scratch.

Same same.

No changes made to .gitconfig (global) nor $GIT_DIR/.gitconfig (Local)

Ah, but then, in unrelated (?) news, GitHub 'informed' me that I needed to update my GitHub (online) account which I promptly did. Ya think? I logged into my GitHub account, added rekey-1 and rekey-2(nd attempt) successfully -

1: The push

**git push origin master**

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Step 2: Ran the ssh telnet test

**ssh -T git@github.com**

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Step 3: Ran the Debug test

**ssh -vT git@github.com**

- See screenshot

[Debug Trace Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii3TX.png)

[Resolution - Same Key, Same Description, Two Areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYI0P.png)

Comment: Found the issue: In the process of cleaning up, I was thinking that only the 'signing' key was needed and removed the 'Auth-Key' FROM GitHub believing it to be redundant. Turns out, the same key must reside in BOTH GitHub buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue occurred after I cleaned (removed) 'excess keys' from GitHub Authentication keys not realizing that a public key is needed in both authent and signing.